# Rounding off in java

Tags: java, decimal

I have a list that contains many decimal values.

- If i get a value of .032 i have to
  round it off to 3.2%
- If i get a value
  of 32.33 i have to round it off to
  32%
- If i get a value of 32.66 i have   to round it off to 33%
- if decimal    digit is 5,6,7,8 or 9
  round up to the    next

how should i go bt dng this?

Comment: are you sure the first rule is correct? it does not seem to match with the others.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Math.round()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29). This correctly rounds a number upwards if the fractional part is 0.5 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question correctly:

For the first point, you can use `DecimalFormat` class, see [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

I'm not sure why you'd want to "round" 32.33 -> 32% as this is not rounding. If you are parsing user input data which could be given in this way, you can divide by 100 (giving 0.3233) and use DecimalFormat.

For the others you can use `Math.round()` as adviced below/above

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.round()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29) and convert it to percent form.

*I doubt about `.032` case. rest are looking good.*

Comment: Thnx guys.tha math.round helped . what i wanted to say was.Example : result 0.322  would be displayed 32% (round to remove decimals, if decimal digit is 5,6,7,8 or 9 round up )and if it is
Example: result 0.023 would be displayed  2.3% ( Put in percent with one place decimal, if decimal digit is 5,6,7,8 or 9 round up as i am a beginner if anyone can give me the logic it wil be very helpful.

Comment: just compare the no and decide it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**MathUtils**](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html) (Apache Commons Math)

```
MathUtils.round(double, scale, roundingMethod);
```

**scale** - The number of digits to the right of the decimal point. (+/-)
**roundingMethod** : `BigDecimal`.ROUND_DOWN, #.ROUND_CEILING, #.ROUND_HALF_UP, ...